# product detail page is not showing

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to get product details by clicking on product at product listing page, when I click on product link then at next page URL is fine http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/2 but product is not showing

controller:

```
  public function productdetail(Request $request, Product $product)
  {
      return view('product.detail', compact('product'));
  }
```

route:

```
   Route::get('/product/{product}','Admin\ProductController@productdetail')->name('product.productdetail');
```

detail.blade.php

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.productdetail', $product->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

      {{ $product->product_name }}

  </form>
```

at listening page m using this link for detail page:

```
  <a href="{{ route('product.productdetail', $product->id) }}" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">

     {{ $product->product_name }}

    </a>
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: provide `dd($product)` in your controller. @dev

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei no error

Comment: @mare96 dd it not showing

Comment: Is the url correctly generated?

Comment: So you are don't hit your action in controller...

Comment: @mare96 so what I do?

Comment: @Jerodev yes url is right

Comment: @dev, can you show the definition of your Product class? usually, the path should be App\Product

Comment: @UdoE.    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_image', 'category_id', 'product_code', 'product_price', 'product_status', 'product_slug'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found where problem is when you provide your controller and routes.

You got route resource:

```
 Route::resource('product','ProductController');
```

And your route for details:

```
Route::get('/product/{product}','Admin\ProductController@productdetail')->name('product.productdetail');
```

Resource will provide same route for show, so you need to change your route with additional parameter like:

```
Route::get('/product/{product}/details','Admin\ProductController@productdetail')->name('product.productdetail');
```

Now you can point to that route and I think now will work.

Comment: sory its still same

Comment: `{{ route('product.productdetail', ['id' => $product->id]) }}` try like this. Did you use with whole object or id? @dev

Comment: with both one by one

Comment: Try how I mentioned in comment. Also you can try `{{ url('/product/', ['id' => $product->id]) }}`

Comment: Hmm.. Can you provide your controller namespace? Because you are created controller in separated folder. Am I right?

Comment: yes in seprate folder   complete controller:    paste.ofcode.org/xD9TGW7uPXbaH5GfvRrsf3

Comment: complete routes     paste.ofcode.org/CEiUYSeLU82AeupJGpjF9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198079/discussion-between-mare96-and-dev).